# Dragging bottom layer only in kineticjs

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I am trying to find a way to drag and reposition an image that is below another (larger) image. So basically I want to make the top image completely ignored by the framework. I have tried making it non-draggable, but it still covers up the bottom image and prevents me from resizing it. Anyone had luck with this?

Comment: as per the framework design, the event is caught by the layer/image that is at the top so its not possible work with something below unless you manually trigger the event for it (after catching on top image)

Answer (score 0):

If both images are in the same layer, then you can change the z-index and move the image to the front on click. ( .moveToTop())

If not, then you have to change the z-index of the layer on click, so that the larger image does not cover the smaller.